# How to log job log in mongodb using talend

Tags: talend, error-log

How to log job log whether the job is succeeded or failed into mongodb once the job has been compeleted in talend

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save the joblog into table, then follow the below steps

Main job --> on subjob ok --> fixedflowinput with variables jobname, success then tdbxxoutput..
Main job --> on subjob error --> fixedflowinput with variables jobname, Fail then tdbxxoutput..